# Parsing XML with varying format

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-twig

Firstly apologies for this noob question, I am new to XML parsing. I try to parse some basic XML using `xml::twig`. I've managed to extract some elements using the below perl script, but I am having some difficulties with others.

I have managed to extract the `itemId` and `title` using the code specified below. However, for some reason the script does not extract the `convertedCurrentPrice`. I would like the price to be extracted - which would be `74` in the below XML snippet. I suspect this is not working because the XML displays the info for the `convertedCurrentPrice` in a slightly different format than the `itemID` and `title`.

How can I alter my script so that the `convertedCurrentPrice` is extracted like the other values?

Here is a sample of the XML file (`testxml.xml`).

```
<itemId>222bb5786411</itemId><title>Radiohead In Rainbows Box Set Vinyl Deluxe Limited Edition</title><sellingStatus><currentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</currentPrice><convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
```

Here is my perl script;

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {item => \&acct}
);
$twig->parsefile("testxml.xml");

sub acct {
my ($t, $elt) = @_;

      for my $tag (qw(itemId title convertedCurrentPrice)) {         
                print $elt->field($tag), "\n";
                    }
                        print "\n";
                        print "\n";
                        }


 __END__
```

Answer (score 0):

First off - in order to answer this properly, we really need some valid XML. Yours isn't.

I think the root of your problem is that you can't actually extract `convertedCurrentPrice` from `item` because it's nested beneath `sellingStatus`

It's hard to be sure though, which is why we really do need valid XML. I've reconstructed yours from a best guess, and that's what I spotted.

Run your XML through a pretty printer:

```
XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented_a') -> parsefile('testxml.xml') ->print;
```

You might find you get something like:

```
<xml>
  <item>
    <itemId>222bb5786411</itemId>
    <title>Radiohead In Rainbows Box Set Vinyl Deluxe Limited Edition</title>
    <sellingStatus>
      <currentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</currentPrice>
      <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
    </sellingStatus>
  </item>
</xml>
```

I would also suggest - this isn't a job for a twig handler, unless there's something else going on, so I would tackle it more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new() -> parse ( \*DATA ); 

foreach my $item ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//item' ) ) { 
   print join ",",( map { $item -> get_xpath($_,0)->text } qw ( itemId title sellingStatus/convertedCurrentPrice )), "\n"; 
}


$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;

__DATA__
<xml><item><itemId>222bb5786411</itemId>
<title>Radiohead In Rainbows Box Set Vinyl Deluxe Limited Edition</title>
<sellingStatus><currentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="GBP">74.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
</sellingStatus>
</item></xml>
```

But you could do:

```
$item -> first_child('sellingStatus') -> field('convertedCurrentPrice')
```

in lieu of doing it via `xpath` expressions.